# Из jar в exe файл

Tags: java, jar, exe

Моя проблема заключается в следующем. Хочу сделать из jar файла exe для того что бы запустить свое приложение на другом компьютере. Использую программу Launch4j без всякого труда создаю exe файл который запускается у меня на компьютере, но как только я пытаюсь запустить этот файл на компьютере на котором не установлена java то у меня ничего не получается и запрашивает установить java(после установки java файл без проблем запускается так же как и на моем компьютере). Можно ли сделать так что бы мое приложение запускалась на других компьютерах без установки java? Подскажите как это сделать.

Comment: Ну вот такая она, Жаба. Без JRE работать не будет...

Comment: надо рядом с exe положить бинари jre и использовать их

Comment: https://www.excelsiorjet.com/