# Изменение формата файла .jar

Tags: jar, exe, форматирование

у меня есть файл с расширением .jar и мне нужно сделать из него файл .exe И будет ли он (exe файл) запускаться без установленной java структуры на пк. Как это сделать?

Comment: Конечно же запускаться он не будет.

Comment: Как тогда переделать его из jar в exe?

Comment: https://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html - но без джавы никак не обойтись.

Comment: Возможно, дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/567171/%d0%98%d0%b7-jar-%d0%b2-exe-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb?rq=1